# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Password' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1

Tags: mysql, apache

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'Password' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1

Please help to resolve the issue

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'domain_name BY 'Password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: You don't set the password in the `GRANT` statement in recent versions of MySQL. That's done in `CREATE USER` and `ALTER USER`.